# Yeoman - Copy directories

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I just started using the amazing yeoman.io generators. Everything was working great, up until I tried to scaffold whole directores. Somehow, this.directory, this.bulkDirectory etc. aren't working. I'm not receieving any errors, nothing copies (while this.bulkCopy does work and gives success message).

Inside the copyMainFiles function, I actually want to copy a complete directory with files to the specified locations. I'm not really looking forward to manually this.copy every file.

**In short: this.directory, this.bulkDirectory and this.copy are not working. 
this.bulkCopy IS working.**

This is de index.js (stripped), I hope someone knows what goes wrong. Yeoman version: 1.4.6

```
    'use strict';
    var util = require('util');
    var path = require('path');
    var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
    var chalk = require('chalk');

var NulvijftigGenerator = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
    promptUser: function() {
        var done = this.async();

        // have Yeoman greet the user
        console.log('asasd');

        var prompts = [{
            name: 'appName',
            message: 'Blablabla'
        }];

        this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
            this.appName = props.appName;
            this.folderName = props.folderName;
            this.templateType = props.templateType;
            this.plugins = props.plugins;

            /* this.addDemoSection = props.addDemoSection; */

            done();
        }.bind(this));
    },
    scaffoldFolders: function(){

        // if the user selected basic webshop, create the required folders
        if(this.templateType == "extrawebshop"){
            // main folder (frontend value in configuration)
            this.mkdir(this.folderName);
            this.mkdir(this.folderName + "/account");
        }

        if(this.templateType == "basicwebsite"){
            // main folder (frontend value in configuration)
            this.mkdir(this.folderName);
        }
    },
    copyMainFiles: function(){

        // if the user selected basic webshop, copy the required files
        if(this.templateType == "basicwebsite"){
            this.directory("basicwebsite", this.folderName);
        }

        var context = {
            site_name: this.appName
        };

        //this.template("_header.html", "app/header.html", context);
    },
    runNpm: function(){
        var done = this.async();
        this.npmInstall("", function(){
            console.log("\nEverything Setup !!!\n");
            done();
        });
    }
});
module.exports = NulvijftigGenerator;
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem better? "_aren't working_" doesn't tell us very much. Are you getting errors?

Comment: Ofcouse, updated the message.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you find the solution for this problem? @YorkKeijzer

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure why your config doesn't work, but, taking it simpler, there are few things to consider:

- `this.directory` actually works,
- it takes source path and destination path as the first two parameters, and
- both paths are relative to `this.sourcePath()` and `this.destinationPath()` respectively.

So, if you're having, say, folder structure like

```
..
templates
  src
    sass
    jsx
  dist
    css
    js
    html
```

then simple

```
writing: {
    app: function() {
        this.directory('src', 'src');
        this.directory('dist', 'dist');
    }
}
```

should work.

But!

The directory is being copied recursively *only* if there is at least one file within its full recursive path. On the other hand, I'm not sure if it's necessary (and doesn't really overcomplicate things) to copy empty folders structure.

Answer (score 1):

In your project you have a `Gruntfile.js`.

In this file you have some copy tasks. You can change this for your needs.

For example I added a custom task in my project for copying language files:

```
copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true, 
          cwd: 'app/assets/lang/', 
          src: ['**'], 
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/assets/lang/'
        }
      ----more code----
```

Edit: After reading your comment, maybe I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Basically it comes down to: this.directory, this.bulkDirectory and this.copy are not working. this.bulkCopy IS working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your grunt script in yeoman project and there look for css and js folder paths  . There add your own custom folder you want to copy.

Comment: Can you maybe give an example? I don't think this is what I mean, I would like to do it through a yeoman generator so I can dynamically add content/variables.